# How do I configure H2 used in @JdbcTest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

How can I configure the compatibility settings used for H2 [@JdbcTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/JdbcTest.html) ?

```
jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
```

I need to execute the following query:

```
SELECT  [ID]
     FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE ID = ? 
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY
```

It can only run **iff SQL Server compatibility mode is activated.**

I cannot find any option to configure tests written in this fashion :

```
@JdbcTest
@Sql(scripts = "/test_setup.sql")
class RepositoryTest {
```

I tried using [@AutoConfigureTestDatabase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/jdbc/AutoConfigureTestDatabase.html) with an `application.properties` in the `test/java/resources/`

with the following input:

```
@JdbcTest
@Sql(scripts = "/test_setup.sql")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
class RepositoryTest {



spring.datasource.url= jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE

spring.test.database.datasource.url= jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
```

None of them have any effect and leads to:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException
```

Comment: Why you are not using [testContainers](https://testcontainers.com/) for this kind of test ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa I cannot spin up dockers. Infra limitations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this article can help you
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source

Ivan!

Comment: This does not show how I can change the datasource for `JdbcTest`.

Comment: Please don't post external links only as the can get removed, outdated, ... Rather summarize the relevant contents of the linked page. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with a Integration Test Slice like `JdbcTest`.

Here is what I did.

I put a `application.properties` file in my `src/test/resources` folder.

it contains the following entries:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:h2Test;MODE=MSSQLServer;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=sa
```

I had to write a full integration test for this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Sql(scripts = "/test_setup.sql")
class RepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Thankfully the `@Sql` still worked. The test_setup.sql was located alongside the `application.properties` in `src/test/resources`.

**Why JDBC test will not work**

The reason is because the configuration is hardcoded into the

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.H2EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer

public void configureConnectionProperties(ConnectionProperties properties, String databaseName) {
        properties.setDriverClass(this.driverClass);
        properties.setUrl(String.format("jdbc:h2:mem:%s;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false", databaseName));
        properties.setUsername("sa");
        properties.setPassword("");
    }
```

There is no way to change that connection string.

This configuration is used in `org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration`

with no way to override the settings.

Maybe a GitHub issue will resolve this.